# breakpoint() python is auto-clearing terminal

Tags: python, bash, debugging, terminal, ipdb

After each step from my code when debbuging the application, the breakpoint() is auto-clearing the terminal. It's so bad because I lose all logs during before step.

Why this is occurring?

obs: The blank spaces is the same thing when type `clear` in terminal

- Running application

[image]

- After breakpoint

[image]

Comment: Images should be avoided. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so that otehr can try ?